# Can I add a web application to an already exisiting web site with InstallShield?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I'm using InstallShield 2020 and trying to configure our web application to be installed as part of an already installed web site.

The main application web site is already installed as, say, "MyCompanysWeb". We have created a new web application that can/should be able to be added to the existing web site as an application. eg:

```
- MyCompanysWeb
|- MyCompanysApp
```

I've done this easily in OctopusDeploy for internal deployments and it was a simple case of nominating the parent web site for the application to be attached to.

With InstallShield however, I need to configure a Web Site first before I can add a Web Application. This is not what I want, the Web Site already exists I just need to hook the application to it.

Would it be feasible to add a dummy web site in InstallShield that would simulate the existing Web Site and then add the Web Application? Sounds like a hack to me, but would that work?

My only other option is to install it as its own web site and ensure I don't have a port number clash.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It's possible.

You need to create a public property for Site Number field of Website in Installshield.
[image]

Now, You have to figure out the Site id of the website where your app needs to go. Set its value to the Site Number property. Make sure to perform these operation before the Installshield IIS custom actions.

For more information:
https://docs.revenera.com/isxhelp23/helplibrary/IISPortSiteNo.htm#configuringservers_1892303268_1067781